# When deleting object from scope, it hides the rest in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a list of clients inside my `$scope.clients` which i use a `ng-repeat` to display.

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients">
   <td class="l-h-3x">{{client.name}}</td>
   <td class="l-h-3x p-t-md text-right">
       <button type="button" ng-click="deleteUser($index)>Delete</button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Now, it works perfectly if i delete the last `client` in the list, it deletes it from my database and removes it from `$scope.clients`. The problem comes when i delete any `client` that is not the last one. It deletes the correct `client` from my database, and removes it from my `$scope.clients`, but then it hiddes all of the remaining `clients` that is below.

Fx.

```
$scope.clients [
{id: 1, name: 'Adam'},
{id: 2, name: 'Nadja'},
{id: 3, name: 'Marc'},
{id: 4, name: 'Casper'}]
```

I delete the `client` where `id = 3` it works like a charm, but when i delete the `client` where `id = 2`, it deletes it from my database and removes it from the scope, but also hiddes the `client` where `id = 3` and `id = 4`.

Below is my function I use at the moment to delete a `client`

```
$http.delete(api.getUrl('user', person_to_delete.id), {
        user: $scope.user
    })
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.clients.splice(idx, 1);
    })
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });
```

After reviewing my question (with the help of your inputs) i discovered some dumb mistakes (sorry about that) and i have now updated my post, but I still have the same issue. It still hiddes `client` 3 & 4, after deleting `client` 2

Comment: I think you need to replace code from `clients.indexOf(client)` to `clients.indexOf($index)`.

$index giving current position on which you called delete function.

Comment: if still not happening then ask.

Comment: @TechnoCrat I just tried it, but it gives me the exact same result as before.

Comment: ok then problem is with for loop only. also instead using client.name you used client.profile.firstname into expression.

Comment: Did you see the fiddle I submitted? Make sure your html is well formed. (e.g. don't forget to close quotes on ng-click directives)

Comment: @Tiago Martins I did, and i don't if it is just me but I can't really see what I am doing wrong by looking at your code, which by the is exactly what I want

Comment: @Backer I'd recommend running your html through a validation tool, if your text editor doesn't do it already (I recommend Sublime Text with a couple of linter plugins). Also check your console for javascript errors. If all seems right, try copying my "version" of your code and adapt it back to your page.

Comment: @Tiago Martins I as well tried that (copying your code and adapt it to mine) but stil without luck, so now I'm starting to suspect that my problem lays somewhere else..

But thanks a lot for taking your time to look at my code guys.

Answer (score 1):

Don't really understand the purpose of using `for` here. After first `splice` your indexes in array are shifted and thats why all items after index has been deleted.

You can use `splice` directly since you known the proper element index.

Also, you can use the power of promises that returned by `$http` service, see example below:

```
$http.delete(api.getUrl('user', person_to_delete.id), {
    user: $scope.user
})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available 
    $scope.clients.splice(idx, 1);
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not going into specifics about your code, check out this 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1herdq4/) I've built from it. Looks like it does what you expected it to do.

```
<html ng-app="clientsApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module("clientsApp", []);
    app.controller("clientsCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.clients = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Adam'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Nadja'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Marc'},
        {id: 4, name: 'Casper'}];

        $scope.deleteUser = function(idx) {
        var person_to_delete = $scope.clients[idx];

            for (var i = $scope.clients.length; i--;) {
                var user = $scope.clients[i];
                if ($scope.clients.indexOf(user) == idx) {
                    $scope.clients.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        };
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="clientsCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="client in clients">
            <td class="l-h-3x">{{client.name}}</td>
            <td class="l-h-3x p-t-md text-right">
                <button type="button" ng-click="deleteUser(clients.indexOf(client))">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is probably in the for loop.

```
for (var i = $scope.clients.length; i--;) {
    var user = $scope.clients[i];
    if (clients.indexOf(user) == idx) {
        $scope.clients.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

You're looping from the end of the $scope.clients list and then moving backwards comparing each $scope.client to each client in some other clients list trying to find one that matches.

If you find one that matches then you're asking if the client in the 'clients' list happens to be in the same index position as the client in the $scope.clients list when it was clicked, and finally if that was true then splice it from the list.

Why is any of that necessary?

You already have the index position of the item that was clicked (from the function argument), why not just use that directly in the splice call?

```
$scope.clients.splice(idx, 1);
```